# How to add a div element to wrap an iframe media embed on Tinymce version 6?

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, tinymce, responsive

I want to add an element div class embed-container as an iframe wrapper when inserting the youtube iframe embed.

```
<div class="embed-container">
 <iframe width="100%" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Then how do you press enter after the div element doesn't generate the div element back.

```
<p>Hello world</p>
<div class="embed-container"><iframe .... ></div> //ENTER 
<div class="embed-container">&nbsp</div> // It should be <p>
<div class="embed-container">&nbsp</div> //
```

I want the youtube iframe embed to have a responsive display on the frontend